# MATLAB: save a class property

Tags: matlab

I'd like to save a particular class property to disk, while ignoring the rest of the class properties. I think MATLAB allows the `saveobj` method to be overridden for this purpose. However, this saves the class object with only that property attached. I want to save the property itself, without any of the class information.

I might think that a suitable method would look like:

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        myProp
    end

    methods
        def b = saveobj(a)
            b = a.myProp;
        end

        def Save(a,fname)
            save(fname,'a.myProp');
        end
    end
end
```

But neither of these have the desired effect. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function itself without having to go through [`saveobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveobj.html):

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        myProp
    end

    methods
        function [] =  save(a,fname,varargin)
            myProp = a.myProp; %#ok<PROP,NASGU>
            save(fname,'myProp',varargin{:});
        end
    end
end
```

Then on the command window:

```
>> foo = myClass();
>> foo.myProp = 4;
>> foo.save('var.txt');
>> bar = load('var.txt','-mat');
>> bar.myProp
ans =
     4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. I was just missing the `myProp = a.myProp;` line

Answer (score 1):

The first method (the one involving `saveobj`) is actually correct. For the purposes of discussion let us consider this simple class:

```
classdef testclass

    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function this = testclass(x)
            this.x = x ;
        end

        function a = saveobj(this)
            a = this.x ;
        end
    end

end
```

When you ask MATLAB to save an instance of your class, it will use the `saveobj` method when you call `save` if one exists. The output of this method can be an object, a struct, an array, whatever. You want to test that this has occurred, and you do something natural like this:

```
>> obj = testclass('hi')

obj = 

  testclass with properties:

    x: 'hi'

>> save tmp.mat obj
>> clear all
>> load tmp.mat
>> obj

obj = 

  testclass with properties:

    x: []

>>
```

And this is where I suspect your confusion arises. You expect obj to be a `char` but instead it's an empty object of class `testclass`. (You can verify that it is just an instance of the object based on the saved definition of the class, and that it is not created by calling the empty constructor.)

This may seem rather confusing until you understand how `loadobj` works. In order for MATLAB to know which static method to call on load, it saves the class definition in conjunction with whatever output you are providing from your custom `saveobj` method. When you call `load` it then loads the class definition and calls the `loadobj` static method if one exists. We can test this by modifying the class definition above:

```
classdef testclass

    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function this = testclass(x)
            this.x = x ;
        end

        function a = saveobj(this)
            a = this.x ;
        end
    end

    methods( Static ) 
        function this = loadobj(a)
            this = testclass(a) ;
        end
    end

end
```

If you set a breakpoint in the `loadobj` method you can verify that the type of `a` is indeed `char` as you expect.

Comment: I was looking for a way to save just the property. I have no intention of restoring the class. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I realize that. The point of inspecting what's going on with the load constructor is to explain why the save method works the way it does. If you are not actually interested in using save/load then you can write methods with any name which save a .mat file.

Comment: Yep, that would've been fine too. Cheers